# Select multiple elements with same id - WebDriverJS

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine

I have to create a test with `Selenium`, `WebDriverJS` and `Jasmine` for a function that displays the content of a `div` only when the button connected to that `div` is clicked, and hide all the other elements with the same `id`.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/XqshE/2/) is the function that needs to be tested, and this is a snippet of the test I have written so far:

```
it('should display "BILL2" when the second picture is clicked and hide the others', function() {
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#img_bill2')).click()
        .then(function(){
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#bill2')).isDisplayed()
                .then(function(displayed) {
                    expect(displayed).toBe(true);
                });
        })
        .then(function() {
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//div[@class="hide", @style="display:none"]')).isDisplayed()
                .then(function(displayed) {
                    expect(displayed).toBe(false);
                })
        });
});
```

I am stuck here since I would like to select all the elements, except the one that is currently shown.

Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue? Maybe using `executeScript()` and create a script to locate all the `divs` with `display:none` style can be a solution?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Instead of finding one element find all the elements with same xpath and assert the count of elements. Since all the elements would have  `@style="display:none"` to ensure that these are not displayed.

Comment: Yes man, this is how I solved it. I simply used `xpath('//div[contains(@class, "hide") and contains(@style, "display: none")]')` and ti worked. Since your solution works and you were the first to comment, you can post it as answer and get the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to solve this without using `.isDisplayed()` by counting the numbers of invisible elements. Since all elements would have `display:none` which will ensure that the elements are not displayed.

```
it('should display "BILL2" when the second picture is clicked and hide the others', function() {
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#img_bill2')).click()
        .then(function(){
            driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#bill2')).isDisplayed()
                .then(function(displayed) {
                    expect(displayed).toBe(true);
                });
        })
        .then(function() {
            driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "hide") and contains(@style, "display: none")]'))
                .then(function(elements) {
                    expect(elements.length).toBe(expectedCount);
                })
        });
});
```